# How to make denormalized table from normalized table for OLAP Database (PIVOT-UNPIVOT)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, normalization, unpivot

**My problem is how to create denormalized (OLAP) table from normalized table.**

I have OLTP database with some data. See the chart below:

[image: OLTP_database diagramm]

Pay particular attention to the tables "Variable", "Variable_Value" and "Variable_Sample".

**Variable:**

[image: Variable]

**Variable_Value:**

[image]

**Variable_Sample:**

[image]

The script that creates the table "Variable_Sample" see below:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VarSample]
AS
BEGIN
    truncate table UIR_DB.dbo.Variable_Sample

Declare params cursor for 
 Select distinct id_variable from UIR_DB.dbo.Variable_Value
open params
Declare @idparam int
Declare @csql nvarchar(max)  = ''
Declare @csql2 nvarchar(max)  = ''
Declare @i int = 1
fetch next from params into @idparam
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
Select @csql2 = @csql2 + ', param' +LTrim(Str(@i))
Select @csql = @csql +  ' (Select value as param'+LTrim(Str(@i))+' from UIR_DB.dbo.Variable_Value where id_variable = '+LTrim(Str(@idparam))+') a'+LTrim(Str(@i))+' cross join'
Set @i = @i+1
fetch next from params into @idparam
end
Select @csql = '
Insert INTO UIR_DB.dbo.Variable_Sample SELECT id, CAST(SubString(Param,6,LEN(Param)-5) as int) param_id, param_val
FROM 
(Select ROW_Number() over(order by '+SubString(@csql2,2,LEN(@csql2)-1)+') id, '+SubString(@csql2,2,LEN(@csql2)-1)+' from '+SubString(@csql,1,LEN(@csql)-11) + ') p
UNPIVOT
   (param_val FOR Param IN 
      ('+SubString(@csql2,2,LEN(@csql2)-1)+')
)AS unpvt
'

print @csql
exec sp_executesql @csql
delete from Sample
Insert into Sample select distinct UIR_DB.dbo.Variable_Sample.idsample from UIR_DB.dbo.Variable_Sample
close params
deallocate params
END
```

I need to create table, something like "Variable_Sample_Olap" following form:

**Variable_Sample_Olap:**

[image]

(Of course, if it would be variable3, ..., variableN, then it would be N columns in "Variable_Sample_Olap".)

**Can someone help me with script, that transforms Variable_Sample in Variable_Sample_Olap?**